# ¿Cómo uso useState en React para modificar una propiedad de un objeto que está en un array?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

mi array de objetos:

```
    const [newe, setNewe] = useState([
        {uno:false},
        {dos:true, seg:false},
    ]);
```

deseo usar SetNewe para escribir un objeto sin eliminar los demás; ejemplo: quiero modificar la propiedad seg del objeto 1 en el array  ¿Cómo se puede hacer esto sin eliminar el objeto 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta accediendo al índice que deseas modificar de la variable `newe` y luego le asignas el valor al state utilizando la funcion `setNewe` la misma referencia:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {

 const [newe, setNewe] = useState([
        {uno:false},
        {dos:true, seg:false},
  ]);
  

  var modificar = () => {
    newe[0].uno = true;
    setNeww(newe); // < ----- la asignas el array modificado
  };

  return (
    <div >
      {newe.map((x) => {
        return <div>{x.uno}</div>;
      })}
      <button onClick={modificar}>Modificar</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: El ejemplo no corre, da el error "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop", además se esta mutando el estado directamente.

Comment: SIIIII!!!!!!! Era tan simple como hacer esto: newe[0].uno = true; me funcionó exactamente como lo necesitaba muuuhcas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando Babel que me imagino que si, puedes usar ES6+ de la siguiente forma.

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    obj1: false,
    obj2: false,
    obj3: false
  });

  const handleClick = () => {
    setState({ ...state, obj2: !state.obj2 }); // propagación
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>{`state obj1: ${state.obj1}`}</div>
        <div>{`state obj2: ${state.obj2}`}</div>
        <div>{`state obj3: ${state.obj3}`}</div>
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>change</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Lo anterior es un enfoque más limpio usando las bondades que nos trae los nuevos features de EcmaScript, acá usamos la propagación `...state` para indicar que conserve todo lo que tiene tal como esta, pero modificando `obj2`.

Te dejo un **DEMO** en [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-spence-n7owe?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona el código pero yo tengo es un arreglo de objetos dentro de un array